# Python: How to create a range for input()

Tags: python, input, range

I'm in the middle of writing some simple Python code, however, I'm still a novice and I've encountered a problem that I have been unable to solve.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")

maths = int(input("Enter your maths test result: "))
psychology = int(input("Enter your psychology test result: "))
economics = int(input("Enter your economics test result: "))
IT = int(input("Enter your IT test result: "))
religion = int(input("Enter your religion test result: "))
biology = int(input("Enter your biology test result: "))
average = (maths + psychology + economics + IT + religion + biology)/6
print "Your average test score is: ", average
minimum = min(maths, psychology, economics, IT, religion, biology)
print "Your lowest score is: ", minimum
maximum = max(maths, psychology, economics, IT, religion, biology)
print "Your highest score is: ", maximum
```

The code above allows the user to enter their test results, and returns their average, minimum and maximum scores. However, I need to create a range so that users cannot enter any results below 0 or above 100, although, I'm unsure how to do so even after trying to find out by myself or online.

I'd appreciate any help regarding my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function that check for the user input that return only when the input is valid, like:

```
def ask_user(msj, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(raw_input(msj))
            if start <= n <= end:
                return n
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("invalid input, try again")
```

and use instead of `int(input(...))`

Comment: I would probably do `def ask_user(msg, start=0, end=100):`

Comment: @cricket_007 good idea, I added it